# Multiple issues with css/Jquery login modal in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

1. Modal finally pops up, but its completely out of proportion and size. in fact, all the form fields are displaced outside the modal box
2. I don't see any functionality... And as an example, the 2 tabs on top, for login/register they are not even clickable
3. Out of despair, I tried pasting the css code in both, The CSS file AND  in a `<style>` tag in the header.php file (remember, I'm in a wordpress environment..)

After trying everything for almost 8 hours straight. I'm about to give up. But let me wait... maybe some one here can figure it out

Here's my code on the front page:

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
  <!-- inser more links here -->
  <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
  <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's my modal code (placed on wrapper-footer.php)

```html
<div class="cd-user-modal">
  <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
  <div class="cd-user-modal-container">
<!-- this is the container wrapper -->   
<ul class="cd-switcher">
  <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">New account</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="cd-login">
  <!-- log in form -->
  <form class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
      <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
      <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
    </p>
  </form>
  <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
  <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
</div>
<!-- cd-login -->
<div id="cd-signup">
  <!-- sign up form -->
  <form class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
      <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
      <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a href="#0">Terms</a></label>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">
    </p>
  </form>
  <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
</div>
<!-- cd-signup -->
<div id="cd-reset-password">
  <!-- reset password form -->
  <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>
  <form class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
      <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
      <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
    </p>
  </form>
  <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a></p>
</div>
<!-- cd-reset-password -->
<a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-user-modal -->
```

And here's my CSS sheet:

```css
    /* -------------------------------- 

xsigin/signup popup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-user-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(52, 54, 66, 0.9);
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
}
.cd-user-modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.cd-user-modal.is-visible .cd-user-modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cd-user-modal-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 3em auto 4em;
  cursor: auto;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher li:first-child a {
  border-radius: .25em 0 0 0;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 .25em 0 0;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #d2d8d8;
  color: #809191;
}
.cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher a.selected {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #505260;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-user-modal-container {
    margin: 4em auto;
  }
  .cd-user-modal-container .cd-switcher a {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
}

.cd-form {
  padding: 1.4em;
}
.cd-form .fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
}
.cd-form .fieldset:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.cd-form .fieldset:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.cd-form label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.cd-form label.image-replace {
  /* replace text with an icon */
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
.cd-form label.cd-username {
  background-image: url("../img/cd-icon-username.svg");
}
.cd-form label.cd-email {
  background-image: url("../img/cd-icon-email.svg");
}
.cd-form label.cd-password {
  background-image: url("../img/cd-icon-password.svg");
}
.cd-form input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.cd-form input.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
.cd-form input.has-padding {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 50px;
}
.cd-form input.has-border {
  border: 1px solid #d2d8d8;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.cd-form input.has-border:focus {
  border-color: #343642;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(52, 54, 66, 0.1);
  outline: none;
}
.cd-form input.has-error {
  border: 1px solid #d76666;
}
.cd-form input[type=password] {
  /* space left for the HIDE button */
  padding-right: 65px;
}
.cd-form input[type=submit] {
  padding: 16px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #2f889a;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.no-touch .cd-form input[type=submit]:hover, .no-touch .cd-form input[type=submit]:focus {
  background: #3599ae;
  outline: none;
}
.cd-form .hide-password {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d8d8;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #343642;
}
.cd-form .cd-error-message {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -35px;
  background: rgba(215, 102, 102, 0.9);
  padding: .8em;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  /* prevent click and touch events */
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0.2s;
}
.cd-form .cd-error-message::after {
  /* triangle */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(215, 102, 102, 0.9);
}
.cd-form .cd-error-message.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s 0, visibility 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-form {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 2em;

  }
  .cd-form .fieldset {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 2em 0;
  }
  .cd-form .fieldset:first-child {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .cd-form .fieldset:last-child {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .cd-form input.has-padding {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 20px 16px 50px;
  }
  .cd-form input[type=submit] {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0;
  }
}

.cd-form-message {
  padding: 1.4em 1.4em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-form-message {
    padding: 2em 2em 0;
  }
}

.cd-form-bottom-message {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.cd-form-bottom-message a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.cd-close-form {
  /* form X button on top right */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  right: 0;
  top: -40px;
  background: url("../img/cd-icon-close.svg") no-repeat center center;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-close-form {
    display: none;
  }
}

#cd-login, #cd-signup, #cd-reset-password {
  display: none;
}

#cd-login.is-selected, #cd-signup.is-selected, #cd-reset-password.is-selected {
  display: block;
}
```

You can see it on the site right now how strange it is opening

[On the top right of the following page is the link that opens the modal...](http://examscan.us/shulemberger/)

Answer (score 0):

First, all your inputs in the modal has the inline style `width: 1903px; position: relative; margin-left: -951.5px; left: 50%;` where do that come from?

The button also has the same inline style `width: 1903px; position: relative; margin-left: -951.5px; left: 50%;`

Overall it seems that you are using a lot of inline styling, positioning and z-indexing to get stuff where you wan't.

You will be better of to give your elements a class that you can reuse and set your styling there.

Comment: Very interesting what you point out. Because I don't see it at all... Can you please point out where you find that? Once I see it, I can try to correct it.

Besides, the whole thing is strange, as it is a moda that I downloaded, and pasted it in fully intact...

Comment: When i go to http://examscan.us/shulemberger/ and inspect element with firebug or chrome devtools.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I'm lost in the sea of wordpress code and/or plugins....   unless there's a way to pinpoint where exactly this setting comes from...  Thanks so much for you input on this

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting what you point out. Because I don't see it at all... Can you please point out where you find that? Once I see it, I can try to correct it.

Besides, the whole thing is strange, as it is a moda that I downloaded, and pasted it in fully intact...